# htaccess redirect homepage to different language

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to achieve a following redirect via htaccess:
Let's say my domain is domain.pl, there is also an english version of the site under domain.pl/en (can't really change that).
I would like to redirect domain.pl -> domain.pl/en for people entering the address for the first time, but I want to avoid situations like someone being on the pl domain clicking the logo to go to homepage somehow ending up on the english version of the site.
Since clicking the logo to go to the homepage while on the polish version still sends you to domain.pl, I figured this might be a problem.

Thanks a lot for any help ;)

Comment: How would you examine if someone is visiting the site the first time?

Comment: Hmm, that's the point, I'm not sure. I think this part might be irrelevant actually, it seems to be handling this part pretty well right now, since it never messes up the language when clicking the logo so maybe the redirect wouldn't change that.